# Polynomial Lagrange Function to get the correct coefficients

Tags: java, math, statistics, polynomials

My aim is to create a polynomial with given coefficients, then evaluate the polynomial on giving points. and then use PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm class to recreate the same polynomial and retrieve the same coefficients.

However, I'm getting different coefficients even that both polynomials have the same degree.

My question is how to get the same coefficients ? is there a way to get all possible polynomials ?

```
 static double [] points= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
// Create polynomial using PolynomialFunction class 
PolynomialFunction pf = new PolynomialFunction(coeffecient); 
System.out.println("-------------------Encoding------------------ \nPolynomial degree: "+pf.degree());
System.out.println("Polynomial: "+pf);
System.out.println("Coffecients: ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pf.getCoefficients()));
evaluatePolynomial(pf, points);
PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm LF = new PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm(points,polynomial_values);
System.out.print("-------------------Decoding------------------ \nDegree of     Lagrange polynomial:");
System.out.println(LF.degree());
System.out.println("Polynomial: "+LF);
System.out.println("Coffecient of Lagrange polynomial:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(LF.getCoefficients()));
```

output:

```
-------------------Encoding------------------ 
Polynomial degree: 15
Polynomial: 40.0 x - 53.0 x^2 - 8.0 x^3 - 29.0 x^4 + 99.0 x^5 + 71.0 x^6 -   86.0 x^7 + 127.0 x^8 + 35.0 x^9 + 14.0 x^10 - 53.0 x^11 + 121.0 x^12 - x^13 + 22.0 x^14 - 27.0 x^15
Coffecients: 
[0.0, 40.0, -53.0, -8.0, -29.0, 99.0, 71.0, -86.0, 127.0, 35.0, 14.0, -53.0, 121.0, -1.0, 22.0, -27.0]
-------------------Decoding------------------ 
Degree of Lagrange polynomial:15
Polynomial:    org.apache.commons.math.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm@5f150435
Coffecient of Lagrange polynomial:
[241664.0, -196608.0, 819200.0, -360448.0, 24576.0, -81920.0, 24576.0, -256.0, 640.0, -28.0, 18.0, -52.921875, 121.021484375, -1.000274658203125, 22.000003814697266, -27.000000070780516]
```

**Update**

I should stick with the following points

```
 points= {34121,51152,59804,40922,41678,33985,55244,61576,41866,37365,63178,45530,52928,35006,34671,43212};

 P(x)= 37.0 + 79.0 x + 95.0 x^2 - 118.0 x^3 + 66.0 x^4 - 47.0 x^5 - 64.0 x^6 + 77.0 x^7 + 7.0 x^8 + 113.0 x^9 - 81.0 x^10 + 36.0 x^11 - 33.0 x^12 + 7.0 x^13 - 91.0 x^14 + 80.0 x^15
```

The result after evaluating on polynomial

```
 (points, P(points))= {(34121,7.914104306379832E69),(51152,3.435734636341671E72),(59804,3.5812547774323177E73),(40922,1.209012191911663E71),(41678, 1.5910403312602316E71),(33985,7.453917205941376E69 ),(55244, 1.0898275780150622E73),(61576,5.5495027051432293E73),(41866,1.702159385167097E71),(37365,3.0906623702059587E70),(63178,8.157747712897765E73),(45530,5.991614888661553E71),(52928,5.732748723914476E72),(35006,1.1620189256906411E70),(34671,1.005938101921578E70),(43212,2.736176231116627E71)};
```

however, send (points, P(points)) to Lagrange interpolation produce wrong coefficients:

```
 -7.125711012263528E27, -1.7102522454360707E26, -3.9998444109905895E24, -1.1156590815779537E23, -1.3650590614545068E21, -8.762203435012037E19, 1.36909428672063078E18, -1.125899906842624E17, 7.0368744177664E14, -2.3089744183296E13, 3.95136991232E11, -3.3554432E9, 1.572864E7, -110592.0, 192.0, 79.38.
```

Any suggested solution?

Comment: Do you need to call `computeCoefficients()` before getting them? If not, it is probably a numerical issue. What points are you feeding in?

Comment: @Nico Schertler I've added points array in the question. I did not call  'computeCoefficients()', since 'getCoefficients()' method calls  'computeCoefficients()' . Also, I cannot call 'computeCoefficients()' since it is protected.

Comment: The given polynomial returns values around 10^18 at the end of your range. This is definitely a numerical issue. It might get better for reasonable input.

Comment: @Nico Schertler  if points array is from 1 to 14 it gives me correct result, can you give me a reasonable input example, it should be 16 numbers.

Comment: Already moving the points towards the origin (i.e. -7 to 8) should produce much better results. You can also try scaling them, e.g. `-1.0, -0.9, -0.8 ...`.

Comment: @Nico Schertler Thank you so much, you're correct. Would you please add your answer 'as answer not comment'  and explain why the points should be like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your example is that the polynomial yields very large values when evaluated at some of your points (mostly the larger ones), while others yield very small values. Since you use a numeric data-type with a fixed bit-depth, the details around zero may get lost due to floating-point precision.

If you examine the result of the Lagrange polynomial, you will see that the higher-order coefficients match. These are the coefficients that are responsible for the large values. If you plot this polynomial, you will hardly see a difference because the wrong lower-order coefficients introduce a very small error (compared to the large scale).

In order to solve this, you should feed in points that produce a smaller dynamic range. What points satisfy the condition depends on the input polynomial. As a general rule of thumb, values close to zero should be ok for most polynomials.

Comment: I should stick to the following values 'double [] minutia={35159,61365,32992,37483,33985,38473,59804,41550,40526,38586,57532,43230,52928,36067,43212,4373};' , unfortunately, I'm getting wrong coefficients. I've tried also to divide values by 10000 and 100000 with no luck .. any suggestions?

Comment: What are those numbers?

Comment: It is minutia points extracted from fingerprint, I should use them to feed the polynomial instead of points array

Comment: Are these the y-values? In that case, they don't look too bad. If they are the x-values, what y-values do you use?

Comment: it is x-values, the y-values is randomly generated number. However, you can check  y-values in the question as an example

Comment: I don't see any y-values in your question.

Comment: if I understand you, the y-values appears in the encoding output as "Coffecients"